# Simple javascript function issue

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass an argument to a onclick function using javascript

I had before

```
 title = createElement('span', {className: 'title', innerHTML: this.Title,
            ID: this.ID, Title: this.Title, onclick: TitleOnClick});
```

I am passing parameter `'test'`..

```
    title = createElement('span', {className: 'title', innerHTML: this.Title,
            ID: this.ID, Title: this.Title, onclick: TitleOnClick(test)});


function TitleOnClick(test){
       alert(test);
}
```

Don't seem to work. Am I doing it wrong? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the call to "TitleOnClick" in another function:

```
title = createElement('span', {className: 'title', innerHTML: this.Title,
        ID: this.ID, Title: this.Title, onclick: function() { TitleOnClick(test); }});
```

(Assumes the variable "test" is declared somewhere, as did your example.)

Answer (score 3):

When you call it that way, what you are doing is setting the value of `onclick` equal to the RETURN value of `TitleOnClick(test)`. What you probably want to do, instead, is something like:

`onclick: TitleOnClick` (note no ()'s) - and then within that method, derive the value of `test` based on context.